# Making a flag in argparse require 2 arguments with different types

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'd like to make a parser for a program like follows `program --serve some/path /file/to/serve.html`

Looking at the argparse documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

I cannot for the life of me figure out how I could parse the first argument of `--serve` as a string and the second as `argparse.FileType('r')`

I'd like to do something like

```py
parser.add_argument('--serve', nargs=2, type=(str, argparse.FileType('r')), action='append', help='...')
```

Is there a way to do this with argparse?

Comment: `type` is a function that is called with a string.  It can't be a tuple, even if the individual elements are themselves functions.  Why don't you just accept both terms as strings (i.e. not `type`), and open the 2nd one yourself.  `FileType` is not all that useful, especially in new Pythons which encourage opening files in a `with` context.

Comment: The `type` documentation that you link covers all that I just said.  It's been expanded a lot since I last read it.

Comment: Because I'd like to verify that the command line argument is formatted as a file before I open it, but only the second argument, not the first

Comment: `FileType` actually opens the file, and leaves it open!  It's a function that takes a string argument, and returns an open file (or raises an error). The `type` argument is not a "type checker".

Comment: I mean, that's not good, but still my question remains... I'd like to verify that the argument passed into my program is an existing file in argparse

Comment: Each of the strings implied by the `nargs=2` is passed to the type function independently.  That is, the function will not be 'told' that it's the first or the second.  There are ways of testing whether a string names a valid file (without actually opening it), but `FileType` does not do that.  You have to use Python OS functions for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement a custom type and instead of using `--nargs=2` you use a delimiter to separate the two arguments, you could do something like this:

```
import os
import stat
import argparse

def mytype(v):
    dirpath, filepath = v.split(':')
    try:
        res = os.stat(filepath)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise ValueError(f'{filepath} does not exist')
    else:
        if not stat.S_ISREG(res.st_mode):
            raise ValueError(f'{filepath} is not a regular file')
    return dirpath, filepath

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--serve', type=mytype, action='append', help='...')

args = p.parse_args()
print(args)
```

If I run this in a directory that contains the file `foo.txt`, we see:

```
# with a file that does not exist
$ python argtest.py --serve somedir:bar.txt
usage: argtest.py [-h] [--serve SERVE]
argtest.py: error: argument --serve: invalid mytype value: 'somedir:bar.txt'

# with a file that *does* exist
$ python argtest.py --serve somedir:foo.txt
Namespace(serve=[('somedir', 'foo.txt')])
```

This isn't opening the file; it's testing that the second argument points to a regular file. You could instead of the file and return a file object instead of the path if you want.

Comment: While this works, it's not very intuitive to the average user